# Realm: Multiple instances, each with own config

Tags: ios, swift, realm

My application uses two separate Realm instances (the second comes from a library).

The application itself uses `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfuguration` and the library creates its own configuration (`Realm.Configuration(...)`).

On runtime (after inspecting with Realm Browser), we see that both instances (each live in its own file) contain the models from both Realms. This, of course, has implications on migrations.

I know that when both use the same configuration we should set [configuration.objectTypes](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#class-subsets), but I didn't expect it to matter when each instance has its own configuration.

How can two distinct configs share any data between them? It seems like a bug in Realm - or maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

An explanation was [posted](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5707#issuecomment-376927851) in Realm's issues on GitHub. I'm copying the response here for future searches:

> By default `objectTypes` will include all `RealmSwift.Object`
>   subclasses, regardless of where they are defined.
>
> A library which uses Realm should override
>   `shouldIncludeInDefaultSchema()` to exclude its types from the default
>   `objectTypes` (i.e. add `public override class func
>   shouldIncludeInDefaultSchema() -> Bool { return false }` to the class
>   definitions) and then explicitly list the types it uses. This lets any
>   applications using the library continue to simply use the automatic
>   class discovery.

The credit goes to [Thomas Goyne](https://github.com/tgoyne) (Realm developer).